# Properly pickling and unpickling a dictionary

Tags: python, pickle

I've just started working with the Pickle module in Python 3.4.0 and trying to apply it to a simple program which handles Categories and Words. So far it stores everything as planned, but when I try to load back what I had dumped into the file, the structure appears to be empty:

```
new_data = int(input("New Data File?\n 1 = Yes\n 0 = No\nChoice: "))
if (new_data == 1):
   f = open('data.txt', 'wb+')
   data_d = {}
   pickle.dump(data_d, f)
   f.close()

PrMenu()
option = int(input("Option: "))
f = open('data.txt', 'rb+')        
d = pickle.load(f)
#Functions inside this menu loop receive the structure (Dictionary)
#and modify it accordingly (add/modify/clear category/word), no
#pickling/unpickling is involved
while (option != 0):
   if (option == 1):
      add_c(d)
   elif (option == 2):
      modify_c(d)
   elif (option == 3):
      clear_c(d)
   elif (option == 4):
      add_w(d)
   elif (option == 5):
      modify_w(d)
   elif (option == 6):
      clear_w(d)
   elif (option == 7):
      pr_cw(d)
   elif (option == 8):
      pr_random(d)

   if (option != 0):
      PrMenu()
      option = int(input("Option: "))


#the output structure would be eg. {category_a:[word1, word2, word3, ...], category_b:[..., ...]}
pickle.dump(d, f)
f.close()
print("End of Program")
```

I'm not sure where the problem is, I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but why are you using `pickle` instead of a more modern/portable/human-readable format like JSON?

Comment: Or even `shelve` for thing-that-looks-like-a-`dict`-but-really-serializes-behind-the-scenes.

Comment: I've read that there are better ways of dealing with these kinds of situations, but I'm required to use Pickle in my Python class at College.

Comment: I'd stay away from crippled the `shelve` module and also from `json`.  Both are terribly limited solutions.  Pickle provides an easy way to extend itself, and thus you can extend it to serialize the entire python language if you are persistent enough.  So why use pickle?  You pickle if you want to a more robust set of serialized objects.  For a good example of extending pickle to serialize almost anything in python, see https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill.  If you want a better shelve, then see https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto.

Besides, the author is stuck with pickle, so pickle it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending data to your file. so the first dataset is the empty dictionary, which you read in, and the second dataset is the filled dictionary, which you never read again. You have to seek back to 0 before writing.